# CasperJS HTTP Auth

Tags: casperjs, basic-authentication

Is there some way to do http authentication using CasperJS?

I need to access a screen with that requires an authentication, so my tests are failing, I can't access the html of these form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need access the html, just call a CasperJS method:

```
casper.test.begin('my test', 1, function suite(test) {

    var siteUrl = 'http://youwebsite.com.br'

    casper.start();
    casper.setHttpAuth('user', 'password');

    ...
```

I hope it can help you